# Search by Date using Linq query

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, linq, datetime

I have Database table and it has a field call **CreatedDate** which is DateTime Format.

Ex: in that field values are saved like `2015-08-27 13:28:50.333` or `NULL`

I wrote following Linq query to search by `type`, `category`, `country`,  `subsidary` and date . `type`, `category`, `country`,  `subsidary` fields are nvarchar field and date is DateTime Field

```
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult FetchProducts(string type, string category, string country, string subsidary, string dateHERE)
    {

        DateTime? mydate = null;
        DateTime date2;
        bool check = DateTime.TryParse(dateHERE, out date2);
        if (check)
        {
            mydate = date2;
        }

        ................


        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(type))
            products = products.Where(p => p.ProductType_ID.StartsWith(type));

        ....................

        if (check)
        {
           products = products.Where(p => p.CreatedDate.Equals(mydate)).ToList();
        }

        ...............

        return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

once I input date and search i'm getting null

this query is working for almost all the fields except `date` . whats the corrects linq query to search a date.

Comment: Step 1. Change you parameter to `DateTime dateHERE` and remove the code where you parse it.

Comment: Your dates are stored in millseconds so its highly unlikely that you will find an exact match using `.Equals()`.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I changed parameter as `DateTime? dateHERE` and linq query as `if (dateHERE.HasValue)
                products = products.Where(p => p.CreatedDate.Equals(dateHERE)).ToList();` but the results is same

Comment: As I noted previously, your `dateHERE` value is unlikely to match one of the existing records to the nearest millisecond. Best guess is you want `.Where(p => p.CreatedDate > d1 && p.CreatedDate < d2)` where `d1 = dateHERE.Date()` and `d2 = d1.AddDays(1)`

Comment: where should I define these `d1 = dateHERE.Date()` and `d2 = d1.AddDays(1)` ?

Comment: If I pass `2015/08/27` as value for dateHERE parameter, after its parse I can see the `mydate` value `27/08/2015 00:00:00` , but my database values stored as `2015-08-27 13:28:50.333` is that because of this

Comment: Define `d1` and `d2` before you do the linq query (`d1` should be 27/08/2015 00:00:00 and `d2` should be 28/08/2015 00:00:00)

Comment: I put following`DateTime d1 = dateHERE.Date();
            DateTime d2 = d1.AddDays(1);` and getting this error with under red wiggly line Date 


`'DateTime?' does not contain a definition for 'Date' and no extension method 'Date' accepting a first argument of type 'DateTime?' could be found`

Comment: DateTime j;
            var o = "2015-08-27 13:28:50.333";
            var date = DateTime.TryParse(o, out j);

            //true
            var flag = j.Date == new DateTime(2015, 08, 27);

Comment: OK, Thats because you must have made it `DateTime? (nullable), in which case you need `d1 = `dateHERE.Value.Date;` - and its `Date` not `Date()` (typo in my comment above)

Comment: then I made it to `, DateTime dateHERE` and `DateTime d1 = dateHERE.Date;` but then whats the if condition to use since `if(dateHERE.HasValue)
                products...` invalid

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your last comment. If its nullable, then `if (dateHERE.HasValue) { DateTime d1 = dateHERE.Value.Date; DateTime d2 = d1.AddDays(1); products = products.Where(....); }`

Comment: What is `products`? Is it an `IQueryable` from a SQL backend? If so, which one? (Like linq-to-sql, EF, ...)

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks lot now its working with your approach but if enter `2015-08-27` as parameter I can get results , record that create date has `2015-08-27 12:02:03.444`  but missing results like following `2015-08-27 00:00:00.000` whats the reason ? . beside I appreciate to mark ur answer as correct

Comment: In that case, make it `.Where(p => p.CreatedDate >= d1 && p.CreatedDate < d2)` - note the `>= d1` - so it includes dates with `2015-08-27 00:00:00.000`. And @GertArnold has already given an answer so you can accept that

Comment: If you don't care about the time, you can change your DB field to just Date as well.

Answer (score 1):

You must truncate time:

```
 ...products.Where(p => EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(p.CreatedDate) == mydate)
```

If you are using EF6, then change `EntityFunctions` to `DbFunctions`.

***Additional info:***

[`EntityFunctions`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.entityfunctions(v=vs.100).aspx) methods are called ***canonical functions***. And these are a set of functions, which are supported by all Entity Framework providers. These canonical functions will be translated to the corresponding data source functionality for the provider. Canonical functions are the preferred way to access functionality outside the core language, because they keep the queries  portable.

You can find all canonical functions [**here**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738626(v=vs.110).aspx) and all Date and Time Canonical Functions [**here**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738563(v=vs.110).aspx).

*Don't forget* to add a reference to `System.Data.Objects` and to `System.Data.Entity`.

Or **additionally** you can truncate time part with that logic:

```
DateTime? myDateTomorrow = myDate;
myDateTomorrow.Value.AddDays(1);

products.Where(p => p.CreatedDate >= mydate && p.CreatedDate < myDateTomorrow);
```

Comment: once i put that `products = products.Where(p => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(p.CreatedDate) = mydate);`

getting this eror `The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable, property or indexer`

Comment: @kez replace `=` to `==` or `.Equals()`

Comment: I intergrate ur 1st solutions but result is same , then tried 2nd solution getting red wiggly line under `AddDays`

Comment: @kez I didn't pay an attention to `DateTime?`. Updated my code with `myDate.Value`

Comment: I integrate 2nd one , now I'm getting whole data set , but its not filter by date , whats to do now

Comment: @kez What is the type of `CreatedDate`? Nullable or not?

Comment: its is `DateTime` format, its nullable . values stored in that field like `2015-08-27 13:28:50.333`

Comment: @kez I have two questions. What is the problem with the first solution? In second solution, it will return all datas which has created date `2015-08-27`. What do you want as a result?

Comment: 1.in first solution im not getting any result. -------------- 2.If I pass `2015/08/27` as value for `dateHERE` parameter,  I want results that all the records that `CreateDate` value has `2015/08/27`

Comment: @kez You have updated your question as `8:50.333 or NULL`. So type is `DateTime?`. Yes?

Comment: Again its loading whole data set ,

Comment: @Kez Have you executed this query on the database? If yes, and did you get the desired result? If yes, then could you show us your sql?

Comment: can i use this as sqlserver query ?

Answer (score 1):

As everybody here already mention you your date `.Equals()` not working becouse of milliseconds i usually use `Date` property of `DateTime` class that get only date part of datatime object so i suggest you to do like this:

```
if (check)
{
    products = products.Where(p => p.CreatedDate != null //check on null
    && p.CreatedDate.Value.Date == mydate).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your query is from a SQL backend you always have to keep in mind that the database engine should be able to turn the generated SQL into an efficient execution plan. So one important factor to look at is index usage. If you transform a database field before using it in a predicate, any index on that field will be disabled:

```sql
WHERE dateField = date -- index on dateField can be used
```

vs.

```sql
WHERE DATEPART(.. dateField ..) = date -- index can't be used
```

So it's probably better to do a range check:

```cs
...
mydate = date2.Date;
...


if (mydate.HasValue)
{
   var mydatePlus = mydate.Value.AddDays(1);
   products = products.Where(p => p.CreatedDate >= mydate && p.CreatedDate < mydatePlus)
                      .ToList();
}
```

This is also called a *sargable* expression.

Answer (score 0):

Other more agile way...

```
Expression<Func<Products, bool>> expresionFinal = p => p.Active;

if (mydate.HasValue)
{
    Expression<Func<Products, bool>> expresionDate = p => (EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(c.CreatedDate) <= mydate);
    expresionFinal = PredicateBuilder.And(expresionFinal, expresionDate );
}

IQueryable<T> query = dbSet;


    query = query.Where(expresionFinal);
```

Comment: Only `<= mydate` gives wrong results. And don't just assume that everybody knows PredicateBuilder.

Comment: why wrong results? we search works, the results are before or same day off mydate.

Answer (score 0):

I`m using this linq query to search in date column:

```
var list = db.records;
DateTime? date_start;

if (date_start != null)
{
   list = list.Where(x => x.date != null &&
   x.date.Value.Date >= date_start.Value.Date);
}
```

This will return all records whit date >= date_start